# Mongodb useUnifiedTopology automatically create a new connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here the reduce nodejs server sample, server.js :

```
async function() start {

    const mongoose = require("mongoose") ;
    const conn = await mongoose.createConnection( "myUrlHere", { useNewUrlParser : true, useUnifiedTopology : true } ) ;
}
start() ;
```

When I go to the mongo shell to check the number of connection I see in the serverStatus() variable current = 2, which is ok because the shell connection itself is counted :

```
>var status = db.serverStatus()
>status.connections
{ "current" : 2 ... }
```

But when I add a simple find query in my script as below :

```
async function() start {

    const mongoose = require("mongoose") ;
    const conn = await mongoose.createConnection( "myUrlHere", { useNewUrlParser : true, useUnifiedTopology : true } ) ;
    const MyModel = conn.model( "MyModel", require( "pathToMySchema" ) ) ;
    const foo = await MyModel.find( {} ) ;
}
start() ;
```

Then, after restart the server.js, in the mongo shell I see current = 3 :

```
>var status = db.serverStatus()
>status.connections
{ "current" : 3 ... }
```

Note, it looks like there is a timeout on this "new" connection because it disappears after a few minutes if I do nothing on the server.

After some tests, I see that when I remove the useUnifiedTopology option everything looks fine (except the deprecation warning) and I see current = 2 as expected.

I am using MongoDB 3.6.3 and mongoose 5.10.0, and I want to know if this behavior is normal? And if so, how to correctly check the number of connections.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you disconnecting when the server process ends?

Comment: @AdamExchange I don't explicitly disconnect, but when I shut down the server I see current = 1 (which is the mongo shell one). So I assume it automatically disconnect when the server process end.

Comment: I don't know for sure but it's likely that you are just experiencing the mongoose connection pooling. The default size is 5 https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection_pools. If you lower that to 1, I wonder if you'll see the same results? If it is determined to be the connection pool, then I would leave it at 5, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: @AdamExchange I have the same result with the poolsize = 1 option, but I noticed that if I remove the await in front of the find query then I have a total of 2 connections in the mongo shell (as expected). My theory is that mongoose creates a new connection for synchronous requests to avoid blocking the initial connection.

Comment: @D.SM Yes I will take that answer, thank you. But I don't understand why I see one more connection when executing synchronous queries, but not with asynchronous ones.

Comment: What are synchronous and asynchronous queries?

Comment: If you remove await, is the query executed at all?

Comment: @D.SM The query is not executed if I remove the await, that explain the issue, because I need to add a callback function as a parameter in order to get the result (and execute the query). Now without the await and with the callback I see 3 connections (mongo shell, driver monitoring, and the find query) so it's fine, thank you.